# I am getting a PDO error which seems related to the Media module

Tags: media

After Drupal 8.8 upgrade media module is not working. 
In admin media links are not working e.g **/admin/content/media**
Error : 
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

> Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'media' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression FROM (SELECT 1 AS expression FROM {media} base_table GROUP BY base_table.vid, base_table.mid) subquery; Array ( ) in Drupal\media\MediaListBuilder->getEntityIds() (line 158 of core/modules/media/src/MediaListBuilder.php).

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling the media module.

Comment: After upgrading, Did you run /update.php?

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have not done the update completely. one part of Drupal updating is Database updating.

there are some solutions to update it.

- solution go to `YOUR_WEBSITE_ADDRESS/update.php`  the go through the steps.
- solution if you have *drush*, run `drush updb`